# VB.net Search for a specific string in .txt

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a text file where I have the following:

```
IDJ blablabla/blablabla: 745 6001230015108                  344 00
1234 6001230015108       blabla
IDJ blablabla/blablabla: 745 6001230015109                  344 00
1234 6001230015109       blabla
IDJ blablabla/blablabla: 745 6001230015107                  344 00
1234 6001230015107       blabla
```

My question is how can I extract from this file the following numbers into a text file:

```
6001230015108                  
6001230015109 
6001230015107
```

I have the following code, but what it does it extracts the whole line and also duplicates.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'read info from the file'
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("D:\input.txt")
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\output.txt")
    Dim strTextFileInfo() As String 'an array of strings for each line'
    Dim arrCounter As Integer = 0   'counter for the array'
    Dim strTextToSearch As String = String.Empty    'text to search'

    'read all lines'
    Do While objReader.Peek <> -1
        'redim the array with the needet elements'
        ReDim Preserve strTextFileInfo(arrCounter)
        'input the info'
        strTextFileInfo(arrCounter) = objReader.ReadLine
        'increase the elements'
        arrCounter = arrCounter + 1
    Loop
    'enter the text to search'
    strTextToSearch = InputBox("Enter text to search")
    'search all elements for the string'
    For i As Integer = 0 To arrCounter - 1
        If strTextFileInfo(i).ToLower.Contains(strTextToSearch.ToLower) Then
            'display the found elements'
            objWriter.WriteLine(strTextFileInfo(i))
            'MessageBox.Show(strTextFileInfo(i))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there something significant about those particular numbers, in terms of this capability being migrated into a larger program, or is the search just arbitrary input, as the snippet indicates? If you're searching a large file for a particular pattern of characters, regular expressions are a good starting point; if you're searching fixed text at fixed positions, that may be overkill. More detail would be helpful.

Comment: Technically I am searching for the number 123 contained in that field. 600 123 0015107. After it finds it I would want to copy the whole number and then copy it.

Comment: The text file is no longer then 1000 lines and it always has the same format as stated in the problem. I only want the output as stated above.

Comment: You could reduce a lot of code by calling [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: So you're always looking for *exactly* nnn123nnnnnnn? If so, that's begging for a really simple regular expression like \d{3}123\d{7}. That combined with the ReadAllLines for a relatively small text file are good jumping-off points..